# Getting 64 bit version of machine.config

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationmanager, machine.config

Right now, I'm calling the following line

```
System.Configuration.Configuration cnf = ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
```

the result is the following
cnf.FilePath == C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

I get the following result on a 32bit 2003 server and a 64 bit 2008 R2 server.
Ideally I would like to return the 64bit folder when installed on a 64bit server.

aka - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Is there a way to get the 64 bit version without resorting to doing ConfigurationFileMaps - such as 
[Configuration examples from Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmachineconfiguration%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Update for comment

- Right now, the platform setting is set to Any Cpu
- I'm running the code in an class that inherits from System.Configuration.Install.Installer of a standard application
- This project where the code is situated is being run as a custom action in a Visual Studio Installer setup project

Comment: What do you have the "Platform target" set to in your project settings?

Comment: Updated the ticket with your answer - it's set to any platform.

Comment: Is this a standard application or a web application?  If it is a web application what is the Application Pool's "Enable 32-Bit Applications" setting?

Comment: I'm running the code in an class that inherits from System.Configuration.Install.Installer of a standard application.

Comment: Is this being included as part of an install application or running via the InstallUtil.exe?

Comment: This project where the code is situated is being run as a custom action in a Visual Studio Installer setup project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above answers, I created a Visual Studio Installer.  It would appear that the installer runs as a 32-bit process by default.  As such any .NET code you have running as the custom Installer action would be running as 32-bit which is why you are only seeing the 32-bit Machine.Config and not the 64-bit version.  This [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd7a85k9.aspx) explains how to create the installer as a 64-bit installer.  A 32-bit installer can install 64-bit items however, a 64-bit installer can only install on a 64-bit OS.  You may need to have two installers created (32-bit and 64-bit) and then have the users use the appropriate version if you want to keep it simple.  After I made the change to the TargetPlatform for the installer it showed up in TaskManager as a 64-bit process.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out.  Since I need it for older servers, I'll probably start playing with some path string (aka framework to framework64) and try the ConfigurationFileMap.